# Creating a button which matches 2 columns and put a value in 3rd column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a button which should populates data by given condition:

Suppose i have a table with 3 columns

```
column1  column2 column3
   a       3       
   b       4
   b       3
   a       4
   b       4
```

the button should only show the data with the "b" value in column1 and "4" in column2. Also, it should put the value "yes" in column3, if it satisfies the above condition.

Comment: `The data is very so please make the range flexible.` Sure. How much are you willing to pay? :|

Comment: sorry, it was a typo mistake :)

Comment: `sorry, it was a typo mistake :) –  jayant singh 4 secs ago` I would recommend that you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first before posting a question.

Comment: okay, will keep that in mind. It would be better if you can give the answer to my problem though.

Comment: `It would be better if you can give the answer to my problem though... –  jayant singh 2 mins ago` Also how will it be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to delete the values in column 1 and column 2 if they are not b or 4.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 2 To 6 'Give the range as per your requirement

 If Cells(i, 1) = "b" And Cells(i, 2) = 4 Then
 Cells(i, 3).Value = "Yes"
 End If


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: No I dont want to delete that data. But thank you this one helped.